How to put uniformly k objects into n cells?
Problem. There are $n$ numbered cells. Each of the $k$ objects ($n<k$) is assigned a priority $p=1, 2, …, n$, with which the object is placed in the $i$-th cell. It is required to put uniformly all objects across all cells, taking into account the priority $b$. Here $b$
is a boundary, the object must be put into a cell with priority not great that $b$.
Here, by "put uniformly" I mean that the number of objects in the cells is the same or differs by no more than $m≤2$.
Let us set $n = 5$ cells, $k = 15$ objects, $b = 3$, $m = 2$, and the table of priorities for $k$ objects and $n$ cells is below. $1$ at the intersection of the 1st row and the 4th column means that for the 1st object the 4th cell is specified with the highest priority.

My solution is:

The numbers 12 and 14 in the 1st row mean that objects with numbers 12 and 14 are placed in cell with number 1. Further in the same row there are 2, 1 and two dashes. This means that only these two objects with priorities 2 and 1, respectively, are placed in the first cell. One can see the sum of priorities is 19.
Question. Can you beat the solution with sum 19?
Also I provide the input table in markdown style.



object\cell
1
2
3
4
5




1
2
4
5
1
3


2
2
4
1
3
5


3
4
2
5
3
1


4
2
3
1
4
5


5
3
4
1
2
5


6
3
5
4
1
2


7
4
3
2
5
1


8
4
5
3
1
2


9
2
5
3
4
1


10
4
2
1
5
3


11
3
2
4
5
1


12
5
1
3
4
2


13
4
2
5
1
3


14
1
3
5
2
4


15
4
3
2
5
1




Can you explain "taking into account the priority of at least b", and possibly give an easier (smaller) example please?

b is a boundary, the object must be put into a cell with prioritet not great that b. For example, for the 1st object (1st row in table):
1 8 7 9 2 11 5 3 6 10 4 and b=3
the possible solutions: cells with numbers 1 (first prioritу), 5 (second), 8 (third), in my solution the cell with number 1 is selected.

I find this question extremely unclear. What is the meaning of the numbers in the "solution" table? What are all the untitled columns? (I'm guessing that the entries in the "objects" column should give the number of objects in their row - but then, how can we have a 12 next to a 1 given the uniformity constraint?) Do you mind explaining your notation and giving a smaller example, ideally with less than dozens of relevant (?) numbers in it?

Your solution violates $b=3$.  For example, you have assigned object $12$ to cell $1$, but that has priority $5$, not $2$.

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $p_{ij}$ be the priority for assigning object $i$ to cell $j$.  Let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether object $i$ is assigned to cell $j$.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij} x_{ij}$$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \\
\max_j \sum_i x_{ij} - \min_j \sum_i x_{ij} &\le m \\
x_{ij} &= 0 &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$ such that $p_{ij}>b$}
\end{align}
The minimum turns out to be

 17,

attained by the following $x$:
   1 2 3 4 5 
 1 1 0 0 0 0 
 2 0 0 1 0 0 
 3 0 1 0 0 0 
 4 0 0 1 0 0 
 5 0 0 1 0 0 
 6 0 0 0 1 0 
 7 0 0 0 0 1 
 8 0 0 0 1 0 
 9 0 0 0 0 1 
10 0 0 1 0 0 
11 0 0 0 0 1 
12 0 1 0 0 0 
13 0 0 0 1 0 
14 1 0 0 0 0 
15 0 0 0 0 1 


 Objects 1 and 3 get priority 2, and all others get priority 1.

